# twitter bootstrap drop down issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using twitter bootstrap for my website. I have put dropdown in collpsable which is in modal window. My problem is the dropdow I have put in collaspable inner, it cutoff the menu. Here is that Image[image]

It should show like this :
 [image]

I have tried by changing the z-index attribute but unable to show it. Can anybody know what is  the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive the css it is using is the .dropdown-menu class whose position is set to absolute. If you change the position to relative it will give you the behavior you desire.

So you could isolate this change in your own .css file so you don't touch the main bootstrap.css file so its easier to update without breaking your styles.

So perhaps something in a custom.css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: relative;
}
```